# How to input a value corresponding to a dictionary list and output the corresponding string?

Tags: python

The objective of the code below is for the user to input a number corresponding to the boss (string) from the outputted list, and then output the full name of the boss. For example, if I input 4, I want the output to say 4. Twin Furies. If I use print(d[4]), then the output is what I expect, however when I use print(d[boss_input]), I get the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\Alex\Desktop\Python Code\Runescape Boss Drop Calculator.py", line 24, in 
print(d[boss_input])
KeyError: '4'

The code:

```
import random

print("RuneScape drop log calculator")

d = {1: "1. Vindicta and Gorvek", 2: "2. Gregorovic", 3: "3. Helwyr", 4: "4. Twin Furies"} # create a library that will map the numeric value to the boss name


boss_name = [
    "1. Vindicta and Gorvek",
    "2. Gregorovic",
    "3. Helwyr",
    "4. Twin Furies"
    ]

print(boss_name)

boss_input = input("Please enter the number corresponding to the boss you would like to calulcate the drop rates for: ")


boss_name.index("2. Gregorovic")



print(d[boss_input])
```

Could someone please let me know what I am doing wrong, I am very new to this so there may well be an easy solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast your input to `int`.

Replace:

```
boss_input = input("Please enter the number corresponding to the boss you would like to calulcate the drop rates for: ")
```

by:

```
boss_input = int(input("Please enter the number corresponding to the boss you would like to calulcate the drop rates for: "))
```

```
print(d[boss_input])
4. Twin Furies
```

**Alternative** with dictionary suggested by @TimRoberts

```
boss_name = {
    "1": "1. Vindicta and Gorvek",
    "2": "2. Gregorovic",
    "3": "3. Helwyr",
    "4": "4. Twin Furies"
    }

boss_input = input("Please enter the number corresponding to the boss you would like to calulcate the drop rates for: ")

print(boss_name.get(boss_input, f"Please select a number between [1-{len(boss_name)}]"))
```

Comment: Or, alternatively, use "1", "2", "3" as your dictionary keys.  That avoids the pain of handling the exception if they enter a non-integer.  The KEY is always be aware of what type you have, and what type you need.

Comment: @TimRoberts. This is a good advice, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Function `input()` returns string, as a keyword you need integer (in that code), so cast it to integer by

```
print(d[int(boss_input)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Corralien or Samor answer will work.  If youre just learning, you can remove most of your code and just use this.

```
print("RuneScape drop log calculator")

d = {1: "1. Vindicta and Gorvek", 2: "2. Gregorovic", 3: "3. Helwyr", 4: "4. Twin Furies"} # create a library that will map the numeric value to the boss name

boss_input = int(input("Please enter the number corresponding to the boss you would like to calulcate the drop rates for: "))

print(d[boss_input])
```